# In jqGrid, can I get number of rows that have certain value only?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem with getting number of rows that I want, not all rows of the grid.

I have a grid like following:

[image]

It is called reportingList and when I say something like

```
var listApp = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getGridParam', records');
```

It will return 3 in that case.

However, I want to figure out how to get number of rows where their type equals to Approval only.

So, in the case above, since there are two rows with approval as their type, out put should be 2 instead of 3.

Following is part of display and my code:

[image]

```
$("#employeeList").jqGrid(
```

(skip)

```
gridComplete : function(){
    $("#btnApprovalCon").on('click', function() {                                   
        var list = $("#employeeList").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); //arrayList                 
        if(list != null){
            var reportListIDs = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            list = list.filter(function(val) {
                return reportListIDs.indexOf(val) == -1;
            });
            if(list.length > 0){
                $.each(list, function(i,v){
                    var rowData = $("#employeeList").jqGrid('getRowData', v);
                    var data = {appset_employeeId: rowData.employeeId, appset_department: rowData.department,
                        appset_position:rowData.title,         
                        appset_employeeName:rowData.employeeName, 
                        type:'Approval'}
                    $("#reportingList").jqGrid('addRowData', rowData.id, data);
                });
            }
        }
        var listApp = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records'); 
        if (listApp > 0) {
            $(".btnSaveRep").button("option", "disabled", false);
        };
    });
},
```

So From employeeList grid, users select a row and click four buttons.  If they clicked approval, it would be added in reportingList with its type as approval.

I do not post in here, but I do have same button to add a row as agreement.

I want to make an approval button disabled when there are five approval rows in reportingList.

Thank you in advance.

FYI, I am using Guriddo jqGrid ver 4.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem like following:

```
var repList = $("#reportingList").jqGrid ('getDataIDs');

var appFin = 0;

$.each(repList, function(i,v){
    var repListData = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getRowData', v);
    var repApp = repListData.type;
    if (repApp == "Approval"){
        appFin++;
    };
});
if (appFin >= 5) {
    $("#btnApprovalCon").button("option", "disabled", true);
    var shouldDel = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    var newShould = [];
    for (var ii=(shouldDel.length-1); ii>4; ii--){
        var dd = shouldDel[ii];
        newShould = [dd];
        $("#reportingList").jqGrid('delRowData', newShould);
    };
};
```

get info of reportingList.

Then when its type is equals to "Approval", plus the count.

Finally, when its count becomes 5, disables the button.

Also, for a case when a user selects more than five rows and tries to add those at once, I set it to delete extra rows besides first 5 rows.